# I am having trouble converting this timestamp to a date in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert this time stamp to a date but cant seem to get it to work. any advice how to do this in R?

1476295761422

Comment: Appears to be epoch time including milliseconds... but you really haven't given enough information to be useful.

Comment: As it includes milliseconds we need to divide it by 1000. Something like this? `as.POSIXct(1476295761422/1000, origin="1970-01-01")`

Comment: thanks kevin. dividing by 1000 works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
as.POSIXct(1476295761422, origin="1970-01-01")
```